# How to get custom provider inside child module from App module?

Tags: node.js, dependency-injection, nestjs, inversion-of-control, nest

I have only two modules:

```
ᅠDriver
    ^
    |
    |
   App
```

In the App module, I add a custom provider (amount)

```
@Module({
  imports: [DriverModule], 
  controllers: [],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: "amount",
      useValue: "200"
    }
  ]
})
```

and I want to get it in the controller of the Driver module, like this:

```
@Controller('driver')
export class DriverController {
constructor(@Inject("amount") private amount: number) { .. }
```

But **Nest** throws an error:

```
Nest can't resolve dependencies of the DriverController (?). Please make sure that the argument amount at index [0] is available in the DriverModule context.
```

Can NestJS get a dependency from another module?

I have no idea how to do it differently

Comment: you need to add that provider in the `DriveModuler`. or make that provider globally available somehow

Comment: @MicaelLevi why if I add the string "amount" to the property `exports` it doesn't work. And if I make the `@Global` module then it works?
How to make available through `exports`?

Comment: I believe you should redesign that. I mean, `DriverController` has one dependency: `amount`. So why not add the module that expose such dependency to the `imports` array of `DriverModule`?

Answer (score 0):

1. Add amount to exports on `App.module`
2. Add `AppModule` to imports on `Driver.module`

When you do these, it will probably work, but it is not very correct to provide and use something from `App.module` hierarchically.

Comment: So this might be the answer our dev read and now our nest app has self injection until we clear this mess. :P

Comment: Until time runs out 

Answer (score 0):

Instead of defining that config directly in the `AppModule`, you could define an specific module (e.g. `ConfigModule`) and import it from your `DriverModule`. It's a better practice than importing the `AppModule` from a child module.